# Echoing out a date from a query

Tags: php, mysql

I would like `$minutes` below to be the oldest `datecommented` from the query (expressed in minutes).  When I echo `$minutes` out, I get a blank result.  What am I doing wrong?

```
$queryuidcount = "SELECT loginid, datecommented 
    FROM comment 
   WHERE (HOUR(NOW()) - HOUR(datecommented)) <= 1 
     AND loginid = '$uid' 
ORDER BY datecommented ASC
   LIMIT 1'"; 
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($queryuidcount);
$minutes = $row2["datecommented"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/mysql-query) on your query before you call [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/mysql-fetch-array) on the result. Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT loginid, datecommented FROM comment WHERE (HOUR(NOW()) - HOUR(datecommented)) <= 1 AND loginid = '$uid' ORDER BY datecommented ASC LIMIT 1');

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$minutes = $row['datecommented'];
```

If your query returns multiple rows, you'll need to iterate through them with a while loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    //Fetch values from $row
}
```

Also, consider using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) instead of the mysql function family.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it in the wrong way. Here you can find some examples.

mysql_fetch_array is not for DB connection or sql query.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php